# Is subclassing from object the same as defining type as metaclass?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-internals, new-style-class

This is an old-style class:

```
class OldStyle:
    pass
```

This is a new-style class:

```
class NewStyle(object):
    pass
```

This is also a new-style class:

```
class NewStyle2:
    __metaclass__ = type
```

Is there any difference whatsoever between `NewStyle` and `NewStyle2`?

I have the impression that the only effect of inheriting from `object` is actually to define the `type` metaclass, but I cannot find any confirmation of that, other than that I do not see any difference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pretty much yes, there's no difference between `NewStyle` and `NewStyle2`. Both are of type `type` while `OldStyle` of type `classobj`.

If you subclass from object, the [`__class__` of `object` (meaning `type`) is going](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Python/ceval.c#l4949) to be used; if you supply a [`__metaclass__` that is going to get picked up](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Python/ceval.c#l4944).

If nothing is supplied as `__metaclass__` and you don't inherit from `object`, [`Py_ClassType` is assigned as the metaclass](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Python/ceval.c#l4961) for you.

In all cases, `metaclass.__new__` is going to get called. For `Py_ClassType.__new__` it follows the semantics defined (I've never examined them, really) and for [`type.__new__` it makes sure to pack `object`](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Objects/typeobject.c#l2164) in the bases of your class.

Of course, a similar effect is achieved by:

```
cls = type("NewStyle3", (), {})
```

where a call is immediately made to `type`; it's just a bigger hassle :-)